# Could not find android error when running make command for Linphone using Cygwin

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, cygwin, linphone

I am trying to setup android linphone project on Window and most of the things I have done. I set environment variable path(system and user) and export path in `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` file which is located in *cygwin* home directory.

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/D:/android-sdk/tools

export PATH=${PATH}:/D:/android-sdk/platform-tools

export PATH=${PATH}:/D:/android-sdk/ndk-bundle

export PATH=${PATH}:/D:/android-sdk

export PATH=${PATH}:/C:/apache-ant-1.9.6-bin/apache-ant-1.9.6/bin

export PATH=${PATH}:/D:/android-sdk/android-ndk-r10e
```

Now when I am running make command on cygwin command prompt in android Linphone directory than I am getting this error: "**Could not find android. Please install android SDK.**"

[image: android linphone setup error]

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that `:` is *both* the linux path delimiter *and* the windows drive indicator. Your

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/D:/android-sdk/tools
```

adds *two* directories to the path, `/D` and `/android-sdk/tools`.
Try `/cygdrive/d/` instead of `/D:`.

Comment: Now I added like this:- export PATH=${PATH}:/cygdrive/d/android-sdk/android-ndk-r10e but same problem.

Comment: Did you replace /D:/ with /cygdrive/d/ _everywhere_? The image shows you probably have a dozen such drive letters in the $PATH.

Comment: what does `echo $PATH` show now ? (Add an UPD to the question)

Comment: At 2nd, please locate the executable and do a `ls -l /path-to-executable`. It must show the permissions, you need the execute (x) permission set for everyone. (On a normal Linux, `chmod a+x myfile` adds the execution permission to a file)

Comment: I am running it on Windows using Cygwin and echo $PATH showing all paths as shown above. I think main problem in setting the path but everywhere I set already.

Comment: If it _is_ "showing all paths as shown above", you still have garbage in the path, all these /D (from $PATH:/D:/something:). Try to get rid of the garbage.

Comment: does `/cygdrive/d/android-sdk/tools/android` in the command line start the Android updater? If yes, { does just `android` start it? } else { where is that executable and is its location in the $PATH ? }

Comment: Now I am going to use Linux. No way to compile Linphone project on Windows as linphone customer supports said.